# How to configure the virtual machine settings in VMware's VSphere Client?

Tags: server, vmware, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I probably got a uncommon problem/question regarding virtualisation.
I want to evaluate certain things of OpenStack framework. I got an esx-server where I have setup a ubuntu server 64 bit. I need virtualisation support to test virtualisation on this virtual server, but when I check (`grep -E 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo`) I don't find any of those cpu flags.

Does anybody know how to configure the virtual machine settings in VMware's VSphere Client to achieve virtualisation support in the virtual instance of ubuntu server?
Or does anybody definitely know that this scenario is impossible?

I'll be glad for any advice/hint to get this run or an answer to the question whether it's possible (source, arguments of opinion preferred ;) )

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get hardware virtualization support inside of virtualization...

Comment: No this wont work, because the emulated virtual CPU does not support it and cannot, else it would bypass itself.

Comment: You can not run KVM, but you could run LXC or OpenVZ or Xen

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment about VMware's products, but i'd suggest using current 12.04/Precise for experimentation with kvm.

What you want to achieve is known as nested virtulisation.  This has been supported with amd64 CPU's for some time now, but only landed for Intel in the Precise version of kvm.

Otherwise, you can avoid this and use qemu (which KVM is based on), and not have hardware acceleration (note, it is MUCH slower), but usable.